# how to start developing with OpenText CASE360

Tags: workflow, case, opentext

I'm the beginner of Case and workflow management and want to use OpenText CASE360 create a simple task can anyone advise me how to create/design/implement etc.

Comment: If you have an installation of case360, the help section covers every topic on creating the various case components.

Comment: Thanks @Adarsh I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first have a local set up of case360. 
Choose a POC topic for the same. and start to build the components step by step.
starting with Casefolder, Process, Queries.etc
Start to build components individually and then try connecting each of them.
The help document covers every topic in details